# Competition for mates in sea horses

Tags: physiology, ecology, ethology

This source [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061009043743AA0em2H)

> ...research has shown that it is STILL the males that compete for
>   females.

says that male sea horses compete for mates but this source [here](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/05/080501125451.htm)

> Females exhibit a competitive behavior that's normally a male-type
>   attribute, and males end up being choosy, which is normally a more
>   female-type attribute.

.says that female sea horses compete for mates.

Can anyone provide me a trustable source regarding this ? I would also like to know if there are any recent papers exploring why males get pregnant in sea horses.

Comment: Is this question more apt for skeptics.se ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to ask about [polyandry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyandry) and [polygyny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygyny)? How do the sources you quote touch on the number of mates per individual?

Comment: @terdon The sources I quote seems to answer the question why males get pregnant but if you read carefully there is a mention of polygyny and polyandry. I will quote those parts--

Comment: Whether they compete or not is one thing, polyandry and polygyny refer to the number of mates per individual. I think you are asking whether males or females compete for mates and display secondary sexual characteristics. That is not necessarily related to polygamy of either sex. The two sources disagree on whether the males or the females compete for mates, my guess is that both do but I don't really know. Interesting question but not related to polyandry or polygyny.

Comment: @terdon Ah I see but in most polygynous socities it is the male that competes for mate. I have never heard that a polygynous society had females competing for mates.

Comment: All I am saying is that competition is not related to polygyny or polyandry. Please [edit] your question so you ask what you actually want to know.

Comment: That second link even says: "*Seahorses, however, are monogamous within a breeding season, and each seahorse only mates with one other seahorse.*"

Comment: @amory edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second paper is an article in science Daily and have a pretty decent source from Texas A&M University. It's much better than the first as it is un-sourced post on yahoo answers.

Source: 
["Male Seahorses Are Nature's Mr. Mom, Researchers Say." ScienceDaily. ScienceDaily, 2 May 2008.](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/05/080501125451.htm)

Why male seahorses gets pregnant?

Genetic answer:

May be because only $MHII\beta$ gene present in the male pouch which carries the babies.

Source and more on this topic:

[The impact of sex-role reversal on the diversity of the major histocompatibility complex: Insights from the seahorse (Hippocampus abdominalis)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3117728/)